# Examples of composition series of size 1 and 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Dummit and Foote, composition series and composition factors are defined as follows.

> #### Definition
>
> In a group $G$ a sequence of subgroups
>   $$
> 1 = N_0 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le ... \le N_{k-1} \le N_k = G
> $$
>   is called a *composition series* if $N_i \trianglelefteq N_{i+1}$ and $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is a simple group, $0 \le i \le k-1$. If the above sequence is a composition series, the quotient groups $N_{i+1}/N_i$ are called *composition factors* of $G$.

To make sure that I'm following these definitions correctly, I'm trying to come up with first few basic examples of composition series, where there is no $N_i$ such that $N_i \ne 1 \land N_i \ne G$.

Am I correct that all the following are true?

- $1$ is a composition series of $1$
- $1$ does not have a composition factor
- $1,Z_p$ is a composition series of $Z_p$ where $p$ is a prime
- $Z_p$ has one composition factor: $Z_p$ where $p$ is a prime

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the cyclic group $C_p$ has a composition series of length one, namely
$$
C_p\triangleright 1.
$$
For length two, consider the symmetric group $S_n$, $n\ge 5$, which has the normal subgroup $A_n$. Hence
$$
S_n\triangleright A_n\triangleright 1
$$
is a composition series of length $2$ with simple factors $C_2,A_n$. For $n=4$ we have the composition series
$$
S_4\triangleright A_4\triangleright V_4 \triangleright \langle (12)(34)\rangle \triangleright 1,
$$
where $V_4\cong C_2\times C_2$ consists of $\{ (1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. The factors are
$C_2,C_3,C_2,C_2$.

Comment: Is the trivial group considered to have a composition series? The definition doesn't seem too explicit on this and it can be interpreted to require `k > 0`. Also, in the text, the first part of the theorem (Jordan-Hölder) that immediately follows the definition states "Let G be a finite group with G not equal to 1, then G has a composition series", explicitly excluding the trivial group. Is this something that differs from text to text?

Comment: The trivial group is not simple by definition, so it cannot have a composition series with a simple factor.

Comment: Hmm, I understand the "with a simple factor" part. Is it still true to just say "the trivial group cannot have a composition series"? I guess I'm trying to understand if, by definition, having a composition factor is a necessary condition for having a composition series. Dummit and Foote's definitions seem to say so, but I see articles online that state "every finite group has a composition series" as well, which would include the trivial group. I'm getting lost because of that.

Comment: You are right, let's not getting lost because of the trivial group. Just define it with the trivial group so that things are convenient (and consistent). For Jordan-Hölder the authors find it worth to exclude the trivial group, but others don't, for composition series.